# How properly sum variable according to date and save result in a separate data frame in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I have data

```
bywells <-
structure(list(Well_N = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("KRT3", "KRT4"), class = "factor"), Date_m = structure(c(16251, 
16281, 16312, 16343, 16373, 16312, 16343, 16373, 16404), class = "Date"), 
    QOM = c(132, 36, 39, 211, 45, 108, 161, 30, 31
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L), .Names = c("Well_N", 
"Date_m", "QOM"))
```

and would like to sum variable QOM monthly and get result like

```
       Date_m QOM
1  2014-06-30 132
2  2014-07-30  36
3  2014-08-30 147
4  2014-09-30 372
6  2014-10-30  75
7  2014-11-30  31
```

Whats the proper procedure to extract unique dates and get sum of QOM according to date?

EDIT:
Thanks, folks. Actually both answers are perfect, but I marked as accepted the one with less points to increase karma. Thanks once more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(bywells)[, list(QOM=sum(QOM)), by=Date_m]
#       Date_m QOM
#1: 2014-06-30 132
#2: 2014-07-30  36
#3: 2014-08-30 147
#4: 2014-09-30 372
#5: 2014-10-30  75
#6: 2014-11-30  31
```

Or using `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(QOM~Date_m, bywells, sum)
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many many ways, and `dplyr` package is one option:

```
library(dplyr)
bywells %>% group_by(Date_m) %>% summarize(QOM = sum(QOM))
```

Answer (score 2):

using `plyr`

```
library(plyr)
summarize(group_by(bywells, Date_m),QOM=sum(QOM))
```

or base `tapply`

```
tapply(bywells$QOM, bywells$Date_m, sum)
```